# Finding the numbers in a given range who have a perfect square for the sum of their divisors and returning them with the associated square

Tags: python, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cpython

How can I optimize the code to run at a minimal time while still using the CPython implementation?

```
 def detdivisors(n):
     """This function tests if the sum of the divisors of a given 
     a number is a perfect square and returns the sum if it is, and 
     false if it is not"""
     import math
     divisors = []
     sum = 0
     for i in range(1,n+1):
         if n%i == 0:
             divisors.append(i)
     for i in range(0, len(divisors)):
         sum = sum + (divisors[i]**2)
     if (math.sqrt(sum)%1 == 0):
         return sum
     else:
         return False
 def list_squared(m, n):
     """This function runs for the previous function and returns a 
     list that has all the numbers that satisfy the condition and 
     their associated sums. """
     answers = []
     for i in range(m, n+1):
     ans = []
     if detdivisors(i) != False:
        ans.append(i)
        ans.append(detdivisors(i))
        answers.append(ans)
     return answers
 num = int(input("Enter the beginning: "))
 end = int(input("Enter the end: "))
 ans = list_squared(num,end)
 print(ans)
```

**I am trying to optimize the code by putting every thing in a single function to reduce the number of function calls, but it is still not giving me the kinds of speed I really want to get. **

Comment: Moving everything into one function won't really do anything to your execution speed. If your looking for speed, CPython is usually a no no, unless you have some C extension you can call to do work outside the interpreter. Also, can you post any timings that you consider slow (or not optimal)? What measures have you tried (other than moving code around) to reduce execution time? With all that said, code redundancy never helps a program.

Comment: What is the expected maximum value of the "end"? Is that value small enough so you can use a stored list of prime numbers? If your "end" is guaranteed to be less than `2**32` (over four billion) then you only need the `6542` prime numbers less than `2**16`. This greatly speed the calculation of the sum of the divisors. If you want to optimize code, you need to consider what trade-offs you are willing to make--in this case, increased memory and pre-computed values. Let me know if you want my code that uses the prime list.

Comment: The expected maximum value is 1000, with a start value of 1. I will really like to have your code, it will definitely be of help. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some pure-Python code that does what you want fairly quickly. This gains speed in mutliple ways. First, it uses a mathematical way to calculate the sum of the divisors of a number, using only the prime decomposition (product of powers of distinct primes) of the number. Second, it uses a previously-calculated list of prime numbers to speed up the prime decomposition. So this code has longer code and uses more memory but is faster. Third, I used Python's built-in `is_integer` function to speed up detection of perfect squares. Last, I removed the error-checking from my code to speed it up. This code works up to the prime number greater than the square of the last number in the prime list. You said in a comment that you need numbers up to one thousand. I increased that to one million, just to be sure, and that takes `168` prime numbers. (If you are sure that you will never need to go above 1000 you can use the first `11` prime numbers, up to `31`.)

I just ran `%timeit` on my code, and it takes `3.26` milliseconds to calculate and print the resulting list up to `1000`. It takes `9.05` seconds to do that for one million. Do you need anything faster?

```
import math

primelist = [
      2,     3,     5,     7,    11,    13,    17,    19,    23,    29,
     31,    37,    41,    43,    47,    53,    59,    61,    67,    71,
     73,    79,    83,    89,    97,   101,   103,   107,   109,   113,
    127,   131,   137,   139,   149,   151,   157,   163,   167,   173,
    179,   181,   191,   193,   197,   199,   211,   223,   227,   229,
    233,   239,   241,   251,   257,   263,   269,   271,   277,   281,
    283,   293,   307,   311,   313,   317,   331,   337,   347,   349,
    353,   359,   367,   373,   379,   383,   389,   397,   401,   409,
    419,   421,   431,   433,   439,   443,   449,   457,   461,   463,
    467,   479,   487,   491,   499,   503,   509,   521,   523,   541,
    547,   557,   563,   569,   571,   577,   587,   593,   599,   601,
    607,   613,   617,   619,   631,   641,   643,   647,   653,   659,
    661,   673,   677,   683,   691,   701,   709,   719,   727,   733,
    739,   743,   751,   757,   761,   769,   773,   787,   797,   809,
    811,   821,   823,   827,   829,   839,   853,   857,   859,   863,
    877,   881,   883,   887,   907,   911,   919,   929,   937,   941,
    947,   953,   967,   971,   977,   983,   991,   997]

def sumdivisors(n):
    """Return the sum of the positive divisors of n. This is guaranteed
    to work if 0 < n < 1000000 and will work for many larger numbers.
    """
    sqrtn = int(math.sqrt(n))
    result = 1
    for p in primelist:
        if p > sqrtn:
            break
        exponentofp = 0
        while n % p == 0:
            n //= p
            exponentofp += 1
        if exponentofp:
            sqrtn = int(math.sqrt(n))
            result *= (p**(exponentofp + 1) - 1) // (p - 1)
    if n > 1:
        result *= n + 1
    return result

num = int(input("Enter the beginning: "))
end = int(input("Enter the end: "))
ans = [n for n in range(num, end+1) if math.sqrt(sumdivisors(n)).is_integer()]
print(ans)
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. I definitely needed something like this.